# MySQL full outer join replacement

Tags: mysql, full-outer-join

I am writing a hockey stat database.  I am trying to calculate total points for players.  total points are a sum from the 1st_assists, 2nd_assists, and goals_for tables.  Originally I had the below code working when I had fully populated tables (IE every player had at least one 1st assist).  Now that I have just one game, the result set is not including the goals_for info, because the players that have the assists, don't have goals.
I need full outer join capabilities and I have read this isn't available in MySQL.  I also read though, one can emulated the full out join by doing a union of a left join and a right join.  Given the complexity of this query as it stands already, I am unable to figure out how to do it.
Here is the query:

```
select p.player_first_name, p.player_last_name, count1, count2, (count1+ifnull(count2,0)) as total_count
from
(select player_id, count(*) count1
from(select * from 1st_assists
union
select * from 2nd_assists) as tem
join players on tem.fk_player_id=players.player_id
group by fk_player_id
order by count(*) desc) q1
left join
(select player_id, count(*) count2
from goals_for
join shots_for on goals_for.fk_shot_for_id=shots_for.shot_for_id
join players on shots_for.fk_player_id=players.player_id
group by player_id) q2
ON q1.player_id=q2.player_id
left join players p ON q1.player_id=p.player_id
order by (count1+count2) desc;
```

Here are the results:

```
player_first_name   player_last_name    count1  count2  total_count
Ray                 Bourque                 1   NULL    1
Dany                Heatley                 1   NULL    1
Mike                Bossy                   1   NULL    1
```

There are 3 other players in this game that scored, which don't appear in the above results.  How do a emulate the full outer join that I need?  That is what I need, isn't it?

here are the table details and the desired results:

```
1st_assists:
    1st_assist_id
    fk_goal_for_id
    fk_player_id

2nd_assists:
    2nd_assist_id
    fk_goal_for_id
    fk_player_id

goals_for:
    goal_for_id
    fk_shot_for_id
    game_winner
    time

shots_for:
    shot_for_id
    fk_game_id
    fk_player_id

players:
    player_id
    player_first_name
    player_last_name



desired query results
player_first_name   player_last_name    count1  count2  total_count
Ray                 Bourque                 1   NULL    1
Dany                Heatley                 1   NULL    1
Mike                Bossy                   1   NULL    1
Wayne               Gretzky              NULL      1    1
Paul                Coffey               NULL      1    1
Bobby               Orr                  NULL      1    1
```

I am really only interested in the total_count value, which is the sum of 1st_assists, 2nd_assists and goals_for.  This query is only based on the first game.  There will be many games.

Comment: we need some test data to test our queries against. Will you consider setting up an [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/) with a useful subset of the data that we can use?

Comment: ...together with a desired result set based upon that data!

Comment: yes.  guys, will do.  Never done SQLFiddle, but let me go do that.  I appreciate your help.

Comment: FULL OUTER JOIN is semantically identical to LEFT OUTER JOIN unioned with (RIGHT OUTER JOIN minus INNER JOIN).